# Symfony sfGuardUserPlugin - check password for any user

Tags: passwords, symfony1, sfguard

How can I check any user's password in Symfony? (not only the logged in user)
(I use sfGuardPlugin)
I've tried like this, but doesn't work:

```
$user = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->find(26);
$is_password_valid = $user->checkPassword('password');
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is not clear for me either.

Comment: ... as above, plus what error are you getting?

Comment: sfGuardPlugin uses Propel, not Doctrine. Do you mean you're using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?